Renders too long in Blender 4.1
I just moved to Blender 4.1 from Blender 4, and suddenly there appeared a problem in render time.
Right now I'm making one model and during that I was using different Blender versions (that is 3.6 LTS,4,and 4.1). In previous versions render time was not so long, but when I had downloaded Blender 4.1, it managed to have 100+ tiles to be rendered, but before that I only had one frame to be rendered. I'll leave here a screenshot, so you get it.
If anyone knows the reason of that, please write it.
By the way, in viewport render time has not changed. Render engine is Cycles.

Asked render settings :

Insert:


Sorry, but what resolution is that image and what have you set for Tile Size in the Performance options? It says in the screenshot it has rendered 0 of 209(!) tiles... on a default 1920×1080 images this would be a tile size of around 100 pixels I guess. That's tiny if you are rendering with the GPU. Are you rendering with the GPU? Is it enabled in the preferences and selected in the render settings? You could at least show some of your settings when you expect, because just showing a blank render result is not really telling us what you did.

I almost changed nothing there.Resolution is 1080x1920 and tile size is 2048 (it is also enabled). Yes , I'm rendering with the GPU

default settings,if I say that briefly

Also, render device is CUDA,memory cache - 4096

Yes. Indeed. My renders take too long as well! Like everybody else's. I want them to be faster very much. Like everybody else. That's CG. This makes no sense as a question on Stack Exchange though.

@roninjan Sorry, but one or more settings must be different than the default, because with a tile size of 2048 and an image resolution of 1920×1080 Blender will exactly render 1 tile, not 209. Even accidentally setting 19200×10800 will only be 60 tiles of that size. Would you mind showing us the render settings or maybe upload your file?

But, as @MartynasŽiemys said, we all want our renders to be quicker. Could you give us at least a hint to which magnitudes it is slower? Not every new version is automatically rendering quicker, so it would be interesting to know if you are talking about 1% to 10% slower or something like 500% to 1000% slower...?

Yes,I got what you said,but unfortunately the point is it rendered 1 tile only as it should in previous versions (like in Blender 4), however it suddenly managed not to work in this version as I downloaded it. :/ In addition , I want to mention the fact that I hadn't changed anything in render settings of that file when I was updating Blender also.

Yes,indeed everyone wants it ,I know it well.But it's too slow,like it has become 100x slower.Answering your question,that 1 tile was taking about 1 minute if it was 256 samples with denoise

I have uploaded the render settings,closed one options are hidden,'cause I didn't even touch them

guess it's more 20x slower,than 100x

could it be a bug?

Tile Size
Since Cycles X arrived in Blender v3.0 on December 6th 2021, Cycles does not need tweaking render tiles to perform better on GPU CPU. Unless you are doing a very high resolution render, you shouldn't tile your render. Hence the default tile size is 2048 since then, and you should leave it there.

Tiles & Memory Usage¶
The render is now progressively refined by default, giving a quicker preview of full render. However when rendering high resolution images with many render passes, memory usage can be significant. For this reason high resolution renders are automatically split into large tiles, and each tile is cached to disk as it is completed.
Previously tweaking tile size was important for maximizing CPU and GPU performance. Now this is mostly automated. There are still two situations where reducing tile size from the default can be helpful:

When there is not enough memory to fit both the scene and render result, reducing tile size makes more memory available for the scene.
When a small object renders very slowly compared to other objects (for example transparent hair), rendering with smaller tiles can help keep the GPU busy.


*Source: Cycles - Blender Developer Documentation

Resolution
If you let the tile size to 2048 and yet Blender says to be rendering 209 tiles, I suspect you are not rendering at 1080x1920 resolution.
In your Output Properties, make sure you entered the correct X and Y resolutions, but also the resolution percentage, which should be at 100%:

Device Settings
You didn't mention which GPU model you have. But AFAIK you can use OptiX on GPUS with Compute Capability 5.0 or higher, which includes GPUs as old as 2014's GTX 750.
So unless you have a more than 10 years old Nvidia GPU or technical issues (which should probably be dealt with), you should be able to use OptiX instead of CUDA.

Side note:
This memory cache is your VRAM used in the Video Sequence Editor, it has nothing to do with rendering your 3D scene:

